# PHP expects a parameter of 1 but a boolean is given?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get my head around this problem and after looking at all the other duplicates of this question, my question still isn't answered.

I'm a beginner at PHP but I'm pretty sure my code is fine... but obviously not.

Any help please?

My code is the following...

```
// Get some site-wide variables from the database first
$settings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings");

// Put the site settings into usable variables
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($settings)) {
    $site_name = $row['name'];
    $site_desc = $row['description'];
    $site_status = $row['status'];
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use functions from [this extension](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-query.php), it's depreciated

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "PHP expects parameter 1 to be of type resource, but boolean given"? This indicates an error in your SQL query, use `echo mysql_error();` to debug. you've also not posted a connection(and please make sure to remove any passwords before trying).

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner in PHP and new to Stack Overflow. I made a mistake guys... I added in or die with the mysql error included and it came back with "No database selected". Also Marty is right with his comment above.

Comment: @Dan `mysql_select_db('database');` but dude, don't concentrate on `mysql_`, you shouldn't learn the outdated stuff. Look on PHP.net how `PDO` works!

Comment: Hi Dan, I tried PDO but it confused me way to much. I'm not sure how to include the select db thing though because added that in is causing more errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is failing, which means that the variable $settings is a boolean FALSE value. Try using this:

```
$settings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings");
if($settings === false){
    throw new Exception(mysql_error());
}
```

Judging from your comments above, you are not selecting your database before you attempt to run the query. Try:

```
mysql_select_db('your_database_name');

$settings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings");
if($settings === false){
    throw new Exception(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Hi Wayne, I'm getting the following now...

    `mysqli_select_db("db_cms");`
    `$settings = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings") or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysqli_error());`

Comment: I used `$database = mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $sql);` and it worked now.